# Create uuid in vmdk without VboxManage

Tags: linux, uuid

How can I add the uuid to the image of the hard disk *.vmdk? I have no rights install the kernel modules, so any command VBoxManage I get:

```
     WARNING: The vboxdrv kernel module is not loaded. Either there is no module
     available for the current kernel (2.6.32-279.5.2.el6.x86_64) or it failed to
     load. Please recompile the kernel module and install it by

       sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup

     You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
     Unknown application - VBox
```

Thanks.